# Restriction of Rademacher Complexity

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science, geometric-measure-theory, machine-learning

Let $F\subseteq C([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R})$ be a finite family of functions, which is non-empty.  Let $A,B$ be subseteq of $[0,1]^n$, again non-empty, and let $Rad(C)$ denote the Rademacher complexity of any $C\subseteq C([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R})$.

Is there a way to compare $Rad(F)$ with $Rad(F_|A+ F|_B)$?